# How do I check if a file exists using parm values?

Tags: c#, parameters, file-exists

I am trying to check if a file path exists on a server so that it can be worked with. I am currently using localhost as the server for testing purposes. I tried `if (File.Exists(filePath1))`  it finds the path, but it looks for the file locally without accessing the server.

How can check if `filePath1` exists in `server1`? I am using the following parameter values to test the solution before it gets deployed.

Parameter values in class ParmNames:

`filePath1 = "C:\\Users\\smithj\\Documents\\file.txt"`

`server1 = "localhost"`

```
public class class1
{
    FileRules putFileRH = new FileRules();
    List<IRuleParameter> FileParms = new List<IRuleParameter>();

    private bool Method1()
    {       
        FileParms.Add(new RuleParms(ParmNames.SourceServer, server1.ToString(), string.Empty));
        FileParms.Add(new RuleParms(ParmNames.FileName, filePath1, string.Empty));

        foreach (var server in FileParms)   //not sure if this actually goes through each server or through each parm  in FileParms
        {
            //if (File.Exists(filePath1))         first attempt
            if (File.Exists(server.ValueEnvironment))   //this attempt doesn't find the file
            {
                ...
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                ...
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

IRuleParameter interface:

```
public interface IRuleParameter
{
    string Name { get; }
    string ValueEnvironment { get; }
    string ValueType { get; }
}
```

Comment: Please provide minimal code that shows all pieces involved into the problem (like `IRuleParameter`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to find all rules with a given name and check condition for some /all of such rules. Use `Where` to filter out rules you want and `Any` or `All` depending on your needs to check condition... With current sample `Any` should be enough:

```
var fileExists = FileParms
   .Where(r => r.Name == ParmNames.FileName) // find all "File names"
   .Any(r =>File.Exists(r.ValueEnvironment) // check if any of the files exist
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you should check for `server.FileName` (or whatever is your property name in the `RuleParms` class)

```
if (File.Exists(server.ValueEnvironment))  
{
      return true;
}
```

In your foreach loop `server` represents your current `RuleParms` item.So you need to check it's property.`FileName` should be your property name that holds the `filePath1` value.

Comment: It gave me the following error: `"IRuleParameter does not contain a definition for FileName"`

Comment: I told you,you should change it.What is your property name ?? provide your `RuleParms` class or `IRuleParameter` interface

Comment: @JohnSmith it should be `ValueEnvironment` according to your parameters order.But I'm not sure.